# Validation Accuracy and loss are not correlated

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I am trying to train a Cnn based model to predict Covid-19 severity (mild, moderate and severe).
I have tried first to fine tune a  pretrained model so I used InceptionResnetV2 and I also built a model from Scratch.

You can find both the layers added in fine tuning case and the architecture of the second model.

In both cases, I am facing a problem that I dont know if I should be calling Overfitting. In fact, the loss and accuracy on the training data are converging but when it comes to validation data, the loss is decreasing with a stable accuracy that cant go over 0.6.

When looking on Internet, most sources mentionned that the problem is due to Overfitting and that I should add Dropout layers and regularization.

I have tried that but I couldn't get good resultats again.

---

-- Fine-tuning:

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
model_name = 'InceptionResNetV2'
base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=img_shape)
# Freeze layers up to the last Inception-ResNet-C block
for layer in base_model.layers:
layer.trainable = False

```
# Add new classification layers
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001)(x)

# Add a new Dense layer with 512 units
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.016), 
                          activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                          bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006), 
                          activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.45)(x) 
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.032), 
                          activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                          bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006), 
                          activation='relu')(x)

# x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.45)(x)        
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(class_count, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

---

-- Model 2 :

```
model = models.Sequential()

# Input layer: 227 x 227 x 3
model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(228, 228, 3)))

# 128 6x6x3 convolutions with stride [4 4] and padding 'valid'
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (6, 6), strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

# 2x2 max pooling with stride [2 2] and padding 'valid'
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

# 96 6x6x128 convolutions with stride [1 1] and padding 'same'
model.add(layers.Conv2D(96, (6, 6), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

# 2x2 max pooling with stride [2 2] and padding 'valid'
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

# 96 2x2x96 convolutions with stride [1 1] and padding 'same'
model.add(layers.Conv2D(96, (2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

# 2x2 max pooling with stride [2 2] and padding 'valid'
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))


# Flatten the tensor
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# 512 fully connected (FC) layer
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu',  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.016), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

# 4 FC layers
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))


model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

    # x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.016), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
    #                           bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializers.HeNormal())(x)
    

# Softmax with 'mild', 'moderate', and 'severe' output
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

---

Epoch 10/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 641ms/step - loss: 3.4313 - accuracy: 0.8171 - val_loss: 3.4623 - val_accuracy: 0.4923
Epoch 11/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 642ms/step - loss: 3.1102 - accuracy: 0.8652 - val_loss: 3.1923 - val_accuracy: 0.5554
Epoch 12/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 643ms/step - loss: 2.8328 - accuracy: 0.8748 - val_loss: 3.0336 - val_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 13/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 643ms/step - loss: 2.5772 - accuracy: 0.8851 - val_loss: 2.7065 - val_accuracy: 0.5806
Epoch 14/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 644ms/step - loss: 2.3492 - accuracy: 0.8869 - val_loss: 2.5096 - val_accuracy: 0.5526
Epoch 15/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 645ms/step - loss: 2.1391 - accuracy: 0.9007 - val_loss: 2.3235 - val_accuracy: 0.5442
Epoch 16/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 644ms/step - loss: 1.9359 - accuracy: 0.9122 - val_loss: 2.1889 - val_accuracy: 0.5470
Epoch 17/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 644ms/step - loss: 1.7612 - accuracy: 0.9188 - val_loss: 2.0408 - val_accuracy: 0.5273
Epoch 18/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 644ms/step - loss: 1.6038 - accuracy: 0.9308 - val_loss: 1.8829 - val_accuracy: 0.5442
Epoch 19/150
52/52 [==============================] - 33s 645ms/step - loss: 1.4605 - accuracy: 0.9308 - val_loss: 1.7065 - val_accuracy: 0.5554